# How do I reset a cached password in emacs for smtp+gnutls

Tags: emacs, smtp-auth, gnutls

I have setup emacs to use gnutls for smtp authentication with a partially complete .authinfo file (it has no password). When I send an email, it prompts for the password, and if I type that in correctly, it works perfectly.

If I type it in incorrectly though, the authentication fails (as it should), but I have to restart emacs to try again because it saves the bad password in memory, and reuses it if I send again. Is there a way to flush the saved password so I will get prompted again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `M-x auth-source-forget-all-cached`.